# excel date time cell being covertet to numeric and cant stop it

Tags: excel, text, formula, apostrophe, vba

i have two sheets the first one to call a value from the second sheet, in the first sheet i have

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,'sheet'!B5:'sheet'!I2500,8,FALSE),"")
```

this works fine for all full text fields

but when i have a date time of 
04/26/2013  11:27:00

it converts it to 41390.47708

if i manually edit the cell and put in an apostrophe it is fine but if i try and use a macro or another column to add the apostrophe it changes it to a number and then adds the apostrophe.

is there a way to get the formula to treat the cell as text

Comment: Do you only need the values in the first sheet to _display_ as date or to contain the text value of the date? It seems to be the latter but I wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a function like VLOOKUP it only retrieves the underlying value from the referenced cell, not the formatting (and display of date and time is achieved by formatting) - can't you just format the cell with the formula in the required format?

Right-click on the cell and choose Format Cells > Number > Custom and type this in the box

`mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`

If the formula might retrieve text or a date/time you can still format it that way because the text will be unaffected